# '%matplotlib notebook' behavior in Jupyter Lab

Tags: ipython-magic, jupyter-lab

Currently Jupyter Labs does not support Java Script,
which causes the ipython magic '%matplotlib inline' to fail with the error: 'JavaScript output is disabled in JupyterLab'

I was wondering if somebody found a workout to create the same behavior as %matplotlib inline in Jupyter Notebooks yet?